# Why are my html links for css stylesheets not working for when the screen is 768px wide?

Tags: html, css, mobile, cross-browser

this are my HTML links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.css" media="(min-width: 768px)" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/mobile.css" media="(max-width: 768px)" type="text/css" />
```

sadly, the mobile CSS stylesheet isn't loading when the screen is 768px wide (iPad), why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually BOTH the "style.css" and the "media.css" stysheets will be loaded because if the screen is exactly 768px wide, both rules apply (768 ist the max of the one and the min of the other).

So probably the mess comes from an unwanted combination of both.

I'd change the rule for the "style.css to min-width: 769px`

Comment: To save future maintenance, you can ideally cascade your media queries as you would your styles. I find that splitting CSS like that causes more maintenance headaches later. You've already got `main.css` applying to everything, so why not work your way up: `(max-width: 768px)` then `(max-width:1200px)`.

Comment: thanks! There is a slight problem, this doesn't work when I enable emulation (console) on the chrome developer option, it doesn't work. On other browsers, it does.